# Can you hide Photos in the iOS's Photos app's hidden folder programmatically via Apple's Photokit/API (or am i stuck to having to do by hand)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, photo, phphotolibrary

Like outlined in these steps:

1. Open your Photos app.
2. Select the photo or video that you want to hide.
3. Tap the share button  > Hide.
4. Confirm that you want to hide the photo or video.

seen here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205891
So needs to hide and place images in the hidden album via Apples Photo App.

It can be a third app that does the hiding if I can do this via an apple API (I'd assume it would be Photokit) just cannot be storing in the third party app and removing them from the Photos app as a way of hiding.

I feel like if it was supported it would be documented here with how to favorite an image but dont see it so dont think it exists https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums

Comment: Hello garrettmac. Please, could you hide an image programmatically using iOS Photokit/Api?, I'm searching, I need to do it. Thanks!